# VM program which stores directly on HDD

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, linux-kvm

I'm looking for a VM program like VMware, LXC, or KVM, which stores the whole hard drive of the guest OS on the host HDD.

`LXC` for instance does this, it stores in `/var/lib/lxc/<machine_name>/rootfs/`, which mounts as `/` on the guest OS. I don't like LXC however because the VMs are not portable at all.

VMware and KVM store the data in a disk image, which I can't really mount while the VM is running.

I want to do development directly in the VM, so I want to point my IDE from the host to a location on the host's hard drive, which maps in the guest OS. Any ideas?

Note: I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

A VM and a host OS cannot share block devices and file systems natively, it's completely corrupt the file system within minutes.

It'll probably make more sense to share a directory in your host file system via NFS and have the VM PXE NetBoot from it.

But if you just wanna R/W access to a project tree rather than the whole root file system in the vm, just using folder sharing, vagrant make this super easy and transparent.

Comment: Like I said, LXC already does that, so it is possible ;)

Comment: LXC are containers. The containers and the host all run within the same kernel, and you cannot access the guest file system tree when it's running, LXC takes a snapshot of the guest file tree and start the container with it in its own kernel namespace, the host environment can't read it while it's running.

Comment: Exactly, so my point was that I don't care if they're actual VMs or containers, as long as they can be easily migrated and store the data on the host's partitions.

Comment: The reason why it matters is you already specify that migrating to bare metal is a requirement, which LXC can't do because it doesn't have its own discrete kernel and boot process.

Sounds like you got it all figure out, so I'll leave it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this feature but in VBOX you can as demonstrated here:
1. http://2stech.ca/index.php/linux/linuxtutotials/readmes/128-mount-a-physical-disk-in-virtualbox
2. http://www.sysprobs.com/access-physical-disk-virtualbox-desktop-virtualization-software

The Second link is for windows, just in case would look for it.